# Scrolling effects not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, effects

Hi I am using `Scroll Content Presenter` in my html template page for giving some effects.But it works only once.First time I scroll down the page the div shows the effect and opacity is set to 1 , so it doesn't show the effect next time.I try to change the condition , but it not working perfectly

My code is ,

```
if(n(this).css("opacity")==0)
{
     u=n(this).attr("data-direction"),
     r=n(this).attr("data-easing"),
     n(this).css({opacity:0,display:"none"});

     switch(o[0]){
          case"blind":
               n(this).show("blind"
                     ,{direction:"horizontal"},1e3)
                     ,n(this).animate({opacity:1}
                     ,{duration:1e3,queue:!1,easing:r}
               );
          break;
     }
}
```

Anyone please help me

Comment: please format your code, makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: Not clear. I saw the information div is on the top, not be blockd by something. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: The site contain some effects http://galtechprojects.com/fionapresentation/PMC1.html .At first time we scroll down , the content is scroll from left to right. then we scroll up and again scroll down the effect is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in scroll up. When you scroll up the page the elements styles must be refreshing or animate them. And before scroll down again, element must get the first state until page can animate them.